# Reading Firebase Data in Foundation for Apps?

Tags: angularjs, firebase, zurb-foundation, angularfire

I'm working on a Foundation for Apps project. I've been able to incorporate an external API to it but can't get data from Firebase.

I installed firebase and angularFire through the terminal by npm. Do i need to include 'firebase' in the application in app.js? or anything in the $inject bellow?

Is there any docs for this out there?

Screenshot of JSON file:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/0qCzM.png

**app.js**

```
   (function() {
   'use strict';

  angular.module('application', [
    'ui.router',
    'ngAnimate',
    'firebase',

    'foundation',
    'foundation.dynamicRouting',
    'foundation.dynamicRouting.animations'
  ])

  .controller("PostListCtrl", function($scope, $firebaseArray) {

  var ref = new Firebase("https://emailangular.firebaseio.com/posts");
  $scope.posts = $firebaseArray(ref);
  })

    .config(config)
    .run(run)
  ;

   config.$inject = ['$urlRouterProvider', '$locationProvider'];

   function config($urlProvider, $locationProvider) {
     $urlProvider.otherwise('/');

     $locationProvider.html5Mode({
       enabled:false,
       requireBase: false
     });

     $locationProvider.hashPrefix('!');
    }

   function run() {
     FastClick.attach(document.body);
    }

    })();
```

**blog.html**

```
---
name: blog
url: /blog
title: Blog
controller: PostListCtrl
---


<div class="post" ng-repeat="post in posts">

      <h3><a href="#">{{post.title}}</a></h3>
      <p>{{post.timestamp}}<p>

      <p>{{post.body}}</p>

</div>
```

Thanks in advance!
-ken

Comment: How do you include your scripts in your index file? Make sure you've actually included angularfire and firebase there.

Comment: do i need to include firebase in the module?  angular.module('application', [
    'ui.router',
    'ngAnimate',
    'firebase',

Comment: I made sure to include Firebase and AngularFire in my index file

<!-- Firebase -->
https://cdn.firebase.com/js/client/2.2.4/firebase.js

<!-- AngularFire -->
https://cdn.firebase.com/libs/angularfire/1.1.1/angularfire.min.js